# How to prove $X$ and $Y$ have normal marginal densities?

Tags: statistics

Let $p_1$ denote the $N(0,0,1,1,0)$ density and let $p_2$ be the $N(0,0,1,1,\rho)$ density. Suppose that $(X,Y)$ have the joint density
$$p(x,y) = \frac{1}{2}p_1(x,y) +  \frac{1}{2}p_2(x,y)$$
Show that $X$ and $Y$ have normal marginal densities, but the joint density is normal, if and only is, $\rho = 0$.

I try to use the definition but cannot go on since the $\rho$ is in the exponential part and seems that I can not split it out from the equation and prove that only if $\rho=0$, the joint density will be normal. Any idea of that?

Comment: What does "the $N(0,0,1,1,\rho)$ density" mean?

Comment: It's a bivariate normal distribution, $\rho$ denotes the correlation between these two variables.